# How to umarshall plain JSON with nested struct

Tags: go, struct

GO newbie question. I have a simple JSON payload here, which I'm trying to unmarshall with a nested struct:

The payload:

```json
{
    "name": "foo-bar",
    "profileName": "my-profile-name"
}
```

and the structs:

```golang
type Project struct {
    Name    string   `json:"name"`
    Profile *Profile `json:"profileName,omitempty"`
}

type Profile struct {
    // Name is the name of the namespace created for the project
    Name string `json:"profileName"`
}
```

After a lot of trials and errors I landed on the solution that works

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Project struct {
    Name    string   `json:"name"`
    Profile *Profile `json:"profileName,omitempty"`
}

type Profile struct {
    // Name is the name of the namespace created for the project
    Name string `json:"profileName"`
}

func (p *Profile) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // try to unmarshal as a string first
    var s string
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s)
    if err == nil {
        p.Name = s
        return nil
    }

    // otherwise unmarshal as a struct
    type Alias Profile
    aux := &struct {
        *Alias
    }{
        Alias: (*Alias)(p),
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &aux); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *p = *(*Profile)(aux.Alias)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    payload := []byte(`{
        "name": "foo-bar",
        "profileName": "my-profile-name"
    }`)

    project := Project{
        Profile: &Profile{},
    }
    err := json.Unmarshal(payload, &project)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Name: %s\nProfile Name: %s", project.Name, project.Profile.Name)
}
```

but this just looks a little too cumbersome and verbose. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```golang
type Profile struct {
    Name string `json:"profileName"`
}

func (p *Profile) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if len(data) == 4 && string(data) == "null" { // null?
        return nil
    } else if data[0] == '"' { // string?
        return json.Unmarshal(data, &p.Name)
    } else if data[0] == '{' { // object?
        type P Profile
        return json.Unmarshal(data, (*P)(p))
    }
    return nil // or return error
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/-rOhbmWvmWs